# Fetch an entity's read-only collection from a separate database

Tags: nhibernate

I'm building a new NHibernate 3.3 application that must connect to a legacy system in order to look up some information about my users.  There's a separate, read-only, database that holds course enrollments that I'd like to use to populate a collection on my Student entity.  These would be components in NHibernate-speak, consisting of a department code and course and section numbers, like "MTH101 sec. 2"

The external database has a surrogate key, the student number, which corresponds to a property in my User entity, but it's not the primary key of a Student.

These databases are on separate servers.  I can't change the legacy database,

Do I have a hope of mapping the enrollments collection as NHibernate components?

Comment: My guesses, I think you will need another `sessionFactory` configured to the legancy database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two Options

When you have multiple databases or multiple database servers that you're trying to link together in a single domain model using NHibernate, you basically have two options.

1. Leverage the database server's capabilities ([linked servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx), etc.) to join the data so that NHibernate only has to worry about connecting to one database.  In your NHibernate mappings, you fully specify the `table` attribute so that the database server knows to query against the other database server.  For your "surrogate key, ... not the primary key", you could map this using `<many-to-one property-ref="...">`.
2. Use multiple NHibernate session factories, one for each database.  You would be responsible for coordinating what gets loaded from which database.  You configure each session factory for just the tables that exist in that database and with the appropriate connection string.  Then, to load the data, you execute two queries, one against one database, and another against the other database.

### Which one?

Which is the right choice?  It depends...

#### Available features

If your database server doesn't have any features to support #1, or if there are other things preventing you from using those features, then you obviously have to use #2.

#### Cross-DB `where` Clauses

#1 gives you more flexibility when writing queries - you could specify `where` clauses that span both databases if you needed to, though you need to be careful that the query you write doesn't require database A to fetch tons of data from database B.  With method #2 you execute a second query to get what you need from database B, which forces you to be more conscious about exactly what data you have to fetch from each database to get the job done.

#### Unenforced relationship

There won't be any foreign keys enforcing the relationship because the data lives in two different databases.  NHibernate (very reasonably) assumes that database relationships are enforced by foreign keys.  Since there's a chance these two databases could be out of sync, #1 will require you to resort to things like `not-found="ignore"`, which has [performance implications](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/relations-not-foundignore).

#### Complexity of Deployment

Inter-database relationships make deploying to various environments (DEV, QA, PROD) difficult.  You can't just deploy the application and database, and make sure the application's connection strings are pointing at the correct databases; instead you also have to make sure that any references inside the databases to other databases are pointing to the correct places.

Given all of the above factors, I usually lean towards option #2, but there are some situations where #1 is just so much more convenient.